# How to prove $-i\gamma_2u_{s}^*(p)=v_{s}(p)$ for Dirac spinors?

Tags: quantum-electrodynamics, representation-theory, dirac-equation, spinors, dirac-matrices

It should be true and it's obvious for $p^{\mu}=(m,0,0,0)$, but I'm having trouble with the gamma matrices Algebra and prove it for general momentum.
I'm using Weyl representation:

$$u_{\uparrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
u_{\downarrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\1\end{pmatrix}
v_{\downarrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\\1\\0\end{pmatrix}
v_{\uparrow}=\sqrt{m}\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\\0\\-1\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$\gamma^0=\begin{pmatrix}\ &\mathbb{I}\\\mathbb{I}&\ \end{pmatrix},
\gamma^i=\begin{pmatrix}\ &\sigma_i\\-\sigma_i&\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

and the Lorentz transformation of Dirac spinor is:
$$\Lambda_s=\mathrm{exp}(i\theta_{\mu\nu}S^{\mu\nu}), S^{\mu\nu}={i\over 4}[\gamma^{\mu},\gamma^{\nu}]$$

Answer (score 0):

I will use Srednicki's conventions. Let
$$u_+(p)=\sqrt{m}\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0},\ 
\upsilon_-(p)=\sqrt{m}\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\-1}$$

Also, the $\gamma$ matrices have the form
$$\gamma^{i}=\pmatrix{0&\sigma^i\\-\sigma^i & 0}$$
with $\sigma^i$ being the $i-$th 2x2 Pauli matrix (see [Pauli Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices)).

Then, one simply has to do the matrix multiplication, i.e.
$$-i\pmatrix{0&0&0&-i\\0&0&i&0\\0&i&0&0\\-i&0&0&0}
\sqrt{m}\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0}=\sqrt{m}
\pmatrix{0&0&0&-1\\0&0&1&0\\0&1&0&0\\-1&0&0&0}
\pmatrix{1\\0\\1\\0}=\sqrt{m}\pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\-1}$$
which is $\upsilon_-(p)$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But this is for the zero momentum, how is this true for general momentum?

Comment: Ahhh sorry, I saw your four-vector and I mistakenly thought that this was the answer you were looking for...

Comment: You can boost before and after applying these matrices. This shows that they hold in every inertial frame.

Comment: @Craig Yes actually this is the part I'm asking for since there is some algebra going on here.

Comment: Purely symbolically, you have shown $\hat{C} u_+(0) = v_-(0)$. If you boost $v_-(0)$ to some arbitrary momentum $p$, what you get by definition is $v_-(p)$. It is a less than commonly known fact that the charge conjugation operator commutes with the generators of the Lorentz group. This means you can commute the boost matrix and the C.C. operator to prove that your identity which is true in the rest frame is true in all frames.

Comment: @Craig you're correct. I now have a complete rigorous proof of this and the commuting property is nowhere near trivial. Although charge conjugation must commute with Lorentz transformation in principle，it still needs a proof. Also the original post is incorrect since Schwartz’s textbook got the spinor solutions wrong. I'll post the  correct version and the answer when I'm available.

Answer (score 0):

It's trivial to show that $$-i\gamma^2 u_s^*(0)=v_s(0)$$

$v_s(p)\ $and$\ v_s(0)\ $are related by a pure boost. We need to work out what a pure boost looks like in terms of generators. A pure boost is defined as follow:

$$B(\eta \hat{p})=R(\hat{p})B(\eta\hat{x})R^{-1}(\hat{p})$$

$B(\eta\hat{x})$ is a boost along the x axis with rapidity $\eta = \mathrm{sinh}^{-1}(|p|/m)$. $\ R(\hat{p})\ $is the rotation which takes the x axis into the direction of $\ \hat{p}$. So:

$$\begin{split}B(\eta \hat{p})&=R(\hat{p})e^{iK_1\eta}R^{-1}(\hat{p})\\&=e^{iR(\hat{p})K_1\eta}\\&=e^{i\eta\hat{p}\cdot\vec{K
}}\end{split}$$

This deduction is just an outline. Details can be filled by using the commutating properties of the generators. Or, one can work in the vector representation explicitly and generalize it to arbitrary representation.

So, we have the generator form of a pure boost along any axis. It must be a pure boost to make sure the properties of the little group come out right for quantum fields. And it's something not to be taken for granted that a pure boost has such a concise generator form, because we know that in most cases, boosting along two different axis is not a pure boost (Thomas precession). Most textbooks don't show the generator form of a pure boost, some gives it without any proof, as in Srednicki. Now let's proceed to prove the charge conjugation relation between spinors.
$$\begin{split}-i\gamma^2 u_s^*(p)&=v_s(p)\\-i\gamma^2e^{-i\eta K^{*}} u_s^*(0)&=e^{-i\eta K^{*}}[-i\gamma^2u_s^*(0)]\\\end{split}$$

So we only need to prove:

$$\gamma^2K^*_j=-K_j\gamma^2$$

This can be checked explicitly since $K_j={i\over 4}[\gamma^j,\gamma^0]={i\over 2}\gamma^j\gamma^0$

Q.E.D.